# Hive Insert Overwrite All Partitions

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

Lets assume, yesterday I loaded data for partition_dates : 01-01, 02-01 till 10-01
When I load data today, I see partition_dates as : 01-01, 03-01 till 11-01, meaning 02-01 partition is not available. But hive is not overwriting or deleting this 02-01 partition.

How can I achieve this functionality dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

[Truncate the table](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+DDL#LanguageManualDDL-TruncateTable) then load dynamic partitions.

```
TRUNCATE [TABLE] table_name [PARTITION partition_spec];
```

Omitting partition_spec will truncate all partitions in the table.

Table should be managed. If it is external, make it managed before truncate:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable SET TBLPROPERTIES('EXTERNAL'='FALSE');
```

[Also you can use drop partition with < or > operator.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56646879/2700344)

Comment: Problem is I can't truncate the table as well. Because I am using it to do incremental merging.

Comment: @PratikGarg Found similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55758889/2700344